# How to say "Born to Heal" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm planning a *motto* for a medical squad: "Born to Heal". I want to know it's Latin translation. Google says its "*Sana natus est*", but there is no way to verify that, without an expert's help.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is this an institution that _was_ born to heal or its members that _were_ born to heal? I'm afraid that if you want to have a verb, you need to choose either plural out singular

Comment: Also do you want to keep it as close to the English meaning as possible, or would you like to concede a little to sound "more Latin"?

Comment: @Rafael Thank you for the warm welcome. I think, if it sounds more latin, it would fit our need the most. And in regards to the first question, we are having a dilemma about it. But basically, both options "members" and "unit" ..born to heal, could be presented, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of one base translation and a number of variations:

> **Ad sanandum nati**,

would be the closest I can think of to the English meaning, while keeping the choice of words made by Google Translate (most of us here are not fans of GTr, but that's a starting point: the words are themselves not wrong).

- I had to chose the masculine plural, which is the right thing to do in Latin (and a number of derived languages) if you are speaking about a group of people that includes both males and females.
- The construction ad+gerund (san-*andum*) is the standard way of conveying the idea of *to heal, in order to heal,* and more generally, *for* [verb]-*ing*

> Ad sanandum nata,

is the singular feminine version, if you are speaking about a feminine abstract noun to denote a group (as in *turba*—band—, *legio*—military unit—, *gens*—clan— etc.). You might also want to use the masculine (*ad sanandum natus*) or the neuter (*ad sanandum natum*), depending of what is the omitted noun.

> **Ad sanandum**,

is—in my opinion— a more Latin option, since Latin mottos tend to [condense Latin structure to its limits](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7078/is-this-translation-of-united-we-light-the-way-correct/7082#7082). It also saves you from the need to choose between singular or plural.

An example of *being born for* [sth] to convey a purpose in life is attested at least in Late Latin (not sure about Classical), e.g. in the Vulgate ([Ioh 18:37](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Jo.html#x18_37)):

> Ego in hoc natus sum, et ad hoc veni in mundum, ut testimonium perhibeam veritati (*the reason I was born and came into the world is to testify to the truth*)

---

According to L&S definition of the verb *[sano](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsano)*, synonyms are *[curo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcuro)* (but it usually prefers to take an object), [medeor](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmedeor) and [medico](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmedico), hence *ad [gentes] curandas* (to heal *people)*, *ad medendum*, *ad medicandum*

Answer (score 2):

I would propose

> sanare nascuntur

*[nascuntur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nascor#Latin)* is the third person plural, so the phrase would be in the sense of an outsider saying "[they are] born to heal". If you want something more involved, like "[we are] born to heal", then you can use

> sanare nascimur

As the *motto* is for a group of people, I would be inclined for the plural, as above. If you want the *motto* to be in the singular, as in "[s/he is] born to heal" or "[I am] born to heal", then you can use

> sanare nascitur

or

> sanare nascor

respectively.

Comment: The infinitive alone wouldn't be a good translation of English "to heal," which is a purpose clause.

Comment: @brianpck mmmm, do you have an idea of what my translation actually means in English?

Comment: Not sure, but it's similar to Spanish. You wouldn't just say "Nací sanar," but "Nací *para* sanar."

Comment: @brianpck But I've seen in many places the infinitive used with the "to" preposition implied. E.g. _considerare_ [here](http://www.drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=6&ch=2&l=3-#x), _clamare_ [here](http://www.drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=6&ch=3&l=3-#x), _exultare_ [here](http://www.drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=6&ch=3&l=7-#x), etc. From these examples is where I got the idea, actually.

Comment: The infinitive of purpose is a Vulgar/Later Latin construction, almost unheard of in "proper" Classical speech. The most famous example I can think of is "quo vadis?" "ad Romam crucifigi" ("where are you going?" "I'm going to Rome to be crucified").

Comment: @Draconis So the answer would be correct in Late Latin but not in Classical Latin? And in which sense _crucifigi_ is different from _sanare_? I don't get it. Doesn't _crucifigi_ also has an implicit "to"? Or is it inherited from the _ad_?

Comment: @luchonacho I've asked a new question about that [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7139/406).