# Can we use the infinitive instead of supine with verbs of motion?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification

I was reading the verb "venio" in my dictionary and I saw this "venire populare" "to come to devastate". Then I checked my grammar about final clauses, and I didn't see anything about the infinitive. (I don't know if this is a typo.) Can this construction happen in Latin?

Answer (score 5):

Not really in Classical prose, but it is sometimes found in poetry and later/popular Latin. *I.e.* it's not a "proper" construction according the grammars, but it can be found.

[When did the infinitive of purpose arise?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/when-did-the-infinitive-of-purpose-arise)
This may be more informative

Comment: Thanks. I think my translations will be more "vulgar" now.