# A translation into Latin of the medical term "curative intent"

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

Would ‘destinatus ad sanandum’ be a good translation of the medical term 'curative intent'?

The phrase 'curative intent' is used specifically for cancer patients where the surgeons or oncologist intends to cure the patient by eliminating or destroying the cancer cells. Thus a surgeon might say ‘I am going to treat the patient with curative intent by surgically removing the cancer tumour and surrounding tissues.’ I am looking for an appropriate Latin phrase that conveys the meaning of the medical phrase and whether other users can verify whether my Latin grammar is correct or to come up with something more suitable.

Answer (score 3):

In September 2018 a related question was asked: [How to say "Born to Heal" in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/how-to-say-born-to-heal-in-latin).

Based on the answers given there, I'd go for *ad sanandum*. Due to the nature of the gerundium, there is no need to further specify "intent".

Answer (score 1):

In legal Latin, "criminal intent" is *mens rea*, literally "a guilty mind". This is separate from *actus reus*, the "guilty action" (i.e. a crime actually committed).

So if it's the *intent* as opposed to the *result* that's important, I would extend JobRozemond's answer, and say that "curative intent" is a *mens ad sānandum*—"a mind dedicated to curing". If you want to say you're doing something "**with** curative intent", that would be the ablative: *mente ad sanandum*.